# Add element to a component of a list in R dynamically

Tags: r, list

How can I add an element to a component of a list in R dynamically?

For example, supose I have a `list` called "mylist" with two components, one called "number" and the other called "numberPowerTwo", as following, and need to add 1 element in each loop cycle to each component of my `mylist` list.

```
N <- 10
mylist <- list(number = c(), numberPowerTwo = c())

for (i in 1:N){
    n <- i
    n2 <- i * i

    mylist[i]$number <- n
    mylist[i]$numberPowerTwo <- n2
}
```

I don't know if this code work because I don't know also how to print the result in a file (using `write` or `write.table`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code below:

```
N <- 10
mylist <- list(number = c(), numberPowerTwo = c())

for (i in 1:N){
    n <- i
    n2 <- i * i

    mylist[['number']][i] <- n
    mylist$numberPowerTwo[i] <- n2
}
```

To output as a file, it depends on format you want. The result is a list, I would recommend `RData`:

```
save(mylist, file = 'mylist.RData')
```

then you can simply `load('mylist.RData')`.

Or you may want an excel file, if you have package `xlsx`, you can output each element of `mylist` as one sheet and all together as one file. Otherwise, you can just `write.csv` for each element of `mylist`.

```
# one file with multiple sheets
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
    write.xlsx(mylist[[i]], 'mylist.xlsx', append = T, row.names = F, 
               sheetName = names(mylist)[i])
}
# separate files for each element
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
    write.csv(mylist[[i]], paste0(names(mylist)[i], '.csv'))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sean Lin! Apparently it worked. How can I print the result?

Comment: Because the elements of your list are always the same length and contain related data, you're better off storing them in a `data.frame`.  Luckily, Sean's code will work just the same.  That way, you can use `write.table` to create a file of the data.

Comment: @GuilhermeCampos Please see updates. Also like Nathan says, you can further manipulate `mylist` to easily output.

Comment: @NathanWerth, thank you! In the example my elements have always the same length, but that's not the case I'm working at. So the former answer was accurate.